# CRUD with login Servlet ,JSPand Mysql login implmentation

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i am learning CRUD and login.i am having problems login part. i can not get it to working on the servlet side,  i have interface userDao :

```
public interface UsersDao {

    public boolean validate(String UserName, String Password);

}
```

UsersDaoImplementation class:

```
@Override
public boolean validate(String UserName, String Password) {
    boolean status = false;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        String query =  "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName=? and Password=?";
     preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement( query );

        preparedStatement.setString(1, UserName);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, Password);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        status=resultSet.next();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

for the servlet this what i have

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String UserName=request.getParameter("UserName");  
        String Password=request.getParameter("Password"); 

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
        session.setAttribute("UserName", UserName);

if (UsersDaoImplementation.validate(UserName, Password))

            {  
                RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jupiter/jupiter.jsp");  
                rd.forward(request,response);  

            }  

        else
        {  
            out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Sorry username or password error</p>");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/system/index.html");  
            rd.include(request,response);  
        }  

        out.close();  
    }
```

What is the right way do reslove this? and what am i not doing right?

Comment: `if (UserName.equals(UserName)` ... what is the intended meaning of this?

Comment: if it matches with the data in the database

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  Won't a string always equal itself?

Comment: that is why i am here looking for answers

Answer (score 1):

First, here you take UserName and Password values from request, probably from a html page.

```
String UserName=request.getParameter("UserName");  
String Password=request.getParameter("Password");
```

Then you compare these values you get with themselves

```
    if (UserName.equals(UserName)
        && Password.equals(Password))
```

So it will always return true.

Second, inside your if statement you call your validate function, but you don't use its return, you just call it.

```
dao.validate(UserName,Password);
```

So, you most likely want to do something like this

```
if (dao.validate(UserName, Password) {
    // user found
}
```

Comment: it still underline the dao,I don't know which Data Access Object to call now as they all been flagged

Comment: what exactly does the flag say?

Comment: Seems like you did not instantiated dao. You need to do something like: UsersDaoImplementation dao = new UsersDaoImplementation(), then call the method validate() using your new dao object.

Answer (score 0):

These line:
 if (UserName.equals(UserName) && Password.equals(Password))

make no sense because the comparisons doesn't have function. You compared the variable Username with himself.

`1 - RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jupiter/jupiter.jsp");
     2 - rd.forward(request,response);
     3 - dao.validate(UserName,Password);`

At first step you redirect, (line 2), after, in next step, you validate (line 3).
I think that you should change the lines 2 and 3.

`1 - RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jupiter/jupiter.jsp");
     2 - dao.validate(UserName,Password);
     3 - rd.forward(request,response);`